# Is it posible to add button in Word online ribbon?

Tags: ms-office, office365, officedev

So I'm trying to find out if its possible to add a button in the word online, word 2016 offline version in the ribbon I will attach an image to clarify the idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV9D3.png)

- So, I would like to know if its possible to add a button in the ribbon for the online word version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution while browsing the new features of office 2016!

Here is the link to the info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt267546.aspx

Although its not really what I ment it is still a button that can be used for a function